# Alternatives to erlang:get_stacktrace/0 for getting information on the caller of a function?

Tags: erlang

I am working on a function that is called from a relatively hot code path in our existing codebase. The first thing the function does is call `erlang:get_stacktrace/0` inside a try catch block to so we can get the stacktrace:

```
the_function() ->  
  [_|Trace] = try error(x) of
     _ -> error(impossible)
  catch 
     error:x -> erlang:get_stacktrace()
  end,
  ...
```

We keep the stacktrace so we have information on the caller of the function. I have read that `erlang:get_stacktrace/0` isn't always a cheap function to call (http://erlang.org/pipermail/erlang-questions/2013-November/075928.html). Since this is on a hot code path I would like to replace it with something simpler. Is there another way I can get information on the calling function, things like module and function name, line number, etc... without having to call `get_stacktrace`?

Comment: The question assumes that getting information about the caller is an absolute requirement. Why do you need it? Do you need it at all times, or only if errors occur? What are you really trying to accomplish? Have you considered requiring callers to simply pass the required info as an argument?

Comment: @SteveVinoski I'm working with an existing codebase, and yes, information on the caller is a requirement. I could update the code so the required caller info could be passed as another argument. That would involve updating multiple calling functions, which is something I would like to avoid. I've heard erlang:process_info/2 may give me the same info and might be cheaper to call than get_stacktrace. Any thoughts on that?

Comment: If it's as hot a function as it seems to be, I'd recommend streamlining it as much as possible, even if it means the caller has to do extra work to invoke it. I don't know whether calling `process_info/2` instead will be better; you'll have to measure that to be sure.

Comment: @SteveVinoski It does look like `process_info/2` is more efficient than `get_stacktrace/0`, at least in my tests.

Comment: @SteveVinoski I think your first suggestion is probably the best solution. I'll have the callers pass in an additional argument. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you need to know where you're getting called from then `get_stactrace` may not be enough because the caller might have been optimized out of the stack.

Instead, I'd consider something like this:

```
the_function(Normal, Args, {Module, Line}) ->
  try something(Normal, Args)
  catch error:x -> print_error(Module, Line).

-define(?the_function(Normal, Args), the_function(Normal, Args, {?MODULE, ?LINE})).
```

Now you change all of your calls to `the_function` into `?the_function`, and the third argument is added for you at compile-time.

You could do a more sophisticated version of this with a parse-transform.

Comment: I did some tracing to verify that the caller is in fact part of the stacktrace. It looks like in all cases the calling function is present in the stacktrace. Using a macro would make the change to the calling functions simpler, but it's still a change I'm hesitant to make. Right now it looks like process_info might be enough and it's a little faster, according to my tests.